# Different stages of learning Arithmetics?

Tags: arithmetic, self-learning, learning

Arithmetics is like the most basic part of Mathematics, but that too takes effort to learn.

How would organize or call different stages of learning arithmetics, or can there be stages?

Can it go from basic to advanced level, or is there advanced level of arithmetics?

Comment: In primary school we spent almost a year just dealing with addition, then two more years on multiplication and division, (and negative numbers), then another year on fractions (rational numbers). I think it's quite a lot of stages. I could probably describe in more detail, but is this what you mean?

Comment: Not clear... maybe [number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_theory#Main_subdivisions) for the "advanced part" of arithemtic.

Comment: I think combinatorics can also be considered a natural step after arithmetics.

Comment: Yes @YuriyS I would also consider combinatorics as well

Comment: This really depends on how mathematics instruction is organized in different jurisdictions. In many places there is an initial phase where students are taught to become familiar with all four operations on relatively small numbers, and then the numbers get progressively larger. After that there is a systematization phase in which students are encouraged to think about some of the abstract properties of the basic operations, and to solve multi-step problems. After that, negative numbers, fractions and decimals are introduced, although this is sometimes concurrent with an earlier phase.